# Getting error while passing value to a constructor having return type void in java?

Tags: java, constructor

I am novice to java and trying to grasp the initial of the language. After going through a lecture on constructor, I am writing a program on that.

Name.java

```
public class Name
{
    public static String f;
    public static String l;
    public void Name(String First,String Last)
    {
        f = First;
        l = Last;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return f + " " + l ;
    }
}
```

NameTest.java

```
public class NameTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Name myName = new Name("Mohammad","Shahjahan");
        System.out.println(myName.getName());   
    }
}
```

Now an error is occured while running it..

```
NameTest.java:5: error: constructor Name in class Name cannot be applied to given types;
        Name myName = new Name("Mohammad","Shahjahan");
                      ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

If I change Name.java as follows, No error is occured.

```
public class Name
{
    public static String f;
    public static String l;
    public Name(String First,String Last)
    {
        f = First;
        l = Last;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return f + " " + l ;
    }
}
```

Where is the error?

Comment: [_Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors do not have return types, this

```
public void Name(String First,String Last)
{
    f = First;
    l = Last;
}
```

should be

```
public Name(String First,String Last)
{
    f = First;
    l = Last;
}
```

also your fields

```
public static String f;
public static String l;
```

should not be `static`,

```
public String f;
public String l;
```

Comment: Oh..Thanks..Please tell me why I can't have public static string ?

Comment: @jahan No, when you don't provide a constructor, the compiler adds a parameterless one for you. This default constructor takes no arguments, but you are trying to provide 2. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: But error is telling a different story?

Comment: @Jahan What different story? `required: no arguments, found: String,String` What else is there?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes I misunderstood that.

Comment: @jahan If your fields are static, then you can never have more then one value regardless of how many instances you create. static is shared among all instances of the class.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can you provide me any link to understand the concept?

Comment: @jahan [Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), and then you should probable read the rest of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor shouldn't have a return type, so

```
public Name(String First,String Last)
{
    f = First;
    l = Last;
}
```

The error you're seeing is occurring because, not finding a constructor, java puts the default constructor in with no method body:

```
public Name(){}
```

So by trying to call `new Name("firstName", "lastName")`, It's telling you that the only existing constructor `Name()` can't accept two string inputs.

Also you should remove `static` from your fields. The fields `firstName` and `lastName` refer to a single Name object - making them static makes them refer to all Name object.